# Evaluating ecological community over time with NMDS?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics, vegan

I have sampling data of insect communities per month for 7 months. The sampling occurred in the same location with the same methods once a month. I want to be able to see community changes over time using non-metric multidimensional scaling. Given the repeat-measure sampling in the data how would this be possible? I have looked around and seen some people running the NMDS analysis on the entirety of their data and then using vectors to from one time period's point to another. If that is in fact the way to analyze the data how would one do that using the R package vegan?

**Here is the data for those who are interested**:

```
df<-structure(list(Site = structure(c(17L, 18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 
18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 
12L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("SHA10RA", "SHA10RB", 
"SHA10RC", "SHA10RD", "SHA10RE", "SHA10RF", "SHA11RA", "SHA11RB", 
"SHA11RC", "SHA11RD", "SHA11RE", "SHA11RF", "SHA1RA", "SHA1RB", 
"SHA1RC", "SHA4RA", "SHA5RA", "SHA5RB", "SHA5RC", "SHA5RD"), class = "factor"), 
    Month = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("April", "August", "February", "July", "June", 
    "March", "May"), class = "factor"), Aphaenogaster.floridana = c(0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Aphaenogaster.treatae = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Brachymyrmex.depilis = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Camponotus.castaneus = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Camponotus.floridanus = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Camponotus.nearctus = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Camponotus.socius = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cardiocondyla.emeryi = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 17L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 22L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Crematogaster.ashmaedi = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cryptopone.gilva = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cyphomyrmex.rimosus = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Discothyrea.testacea = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Dorymyrmex.bossutus = c(0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Dorymyrmex.brunei = c(5L, 
    11L, 8L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 23L, 23L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 9L, 21L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 43L, 32L, 
    9L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 22L, 21L, 2L, 12L, 62L, 30L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
    7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 37L, 20L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 
    2L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 56L, 
    0L), Forelius.pruinoses = c(13L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    4L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 81L, 14L, 
    27L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 23L, 32L, 29L, 22L, 26L, 7L, 24L, 
    18L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 37L, 17L, 10L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 37L, 
    22L, 11L, 11L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L), Formica.Archboldi = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Formica.pallidefulva = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hypoponera.opacior = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Monomorium.pharonsis = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Nylanderia.arenivaga = c(9L, 
    10L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 
    22L, 14L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 14L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), Nylanderia.wojciki = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Odontomachus.brunneus = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pachycondyla.stigma = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pheidole.adrianoi = c(1L, 
    0L, 3L, 34L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 162L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pheidole.carroli = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pheidole.dentata = c(0L, 
    2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Pheidole.dentigula = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pheidole.floridana = c(16L, 
    10L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 17L, 9L, 16L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 19L, 0L, 14L, 6L, 17L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 
    9L, 0L, 32L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 32L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 24L, 
    64L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 70L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 12L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 12L, 17L, 3L, 
    0L), Pheidole.metallescens = c(0L, 0L, 52L, 0L, 96L, 2L, 
    0L, 3L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 25L, 19L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 110L, 42L, 55L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 90L, 
    16L, 57L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 1L, 42L, 8L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 28L, 14L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pheidole.moerens = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pheidole.morrissi = c(0L, 
    84L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 26L, 48L, 11L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 47L, 52L, 98L, 41L, 0L, 287L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 
    0L, 119L, 16L, 0L, 240L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 136L, 49L, 39L, 
    295L, 0L, 91L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 29L, 13L, 55L, 10L, 9L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 1L, 16L, 16L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    3L, 13L, 47L, 16L), Pheidole.tysoni = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pogonomyrmex.badius = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    6L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
    0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L), Prenelopis.imparis = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Solenopsis.carolinensis = c(4L, 
    3L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 24L, 9L, 23L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 34L, 2L, 13L, 24L, 12L, 
    6L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 15L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 
    13L, 29L, 7L, 4L, 24L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 12L, 21L, 9L, 
    6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 19L, 3L, 24L, 
    8L), Solenopsis.invicta = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Solenopsis.globularia = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Solenopsis.nickersoni = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Solenopsis.pergandei = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Solenopsis.tennessensis = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Strumigenys.eggersi = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Strumigenys.emmae = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Temnothorax.pergandei = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Temnothorax.texanus = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Trachymyrmex.septentrionalis = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(5L, 
6L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 25L, 26L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 45L, 46L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
57L, 59L, 60L, 65L, 66L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 77L, 79L, 80L, 
85L, 86L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 97L, 99L, 100L, 105L, 106L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 119L, 120L, 125L, 126L, 131L, 
132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 137L, 139L, 140L))
```

UPDATE*  I was able to figure this question out if people are ever in the same situation. I ultimately ran an NMDS analysis on the species X site matrix. I then calculated centroid positions in this multidimensional space from clusters based on time periods. These centroids were then plotted with arrows/vectors in chronological order. The direction and length of these vectors were then used to identify the changes in beta diversity between communities at certain time points (e.g. shorter vectors represent lower levels of change in community structure).

Comment: That seems reasonable. Can you give us some data to play with?

Comment: Hi @BenBolker I just added the data. Thanks so much!